# How to connect Office365 as active directory to my network?

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365, azure-active-directory

I want to connect my Office 365 online Active directory to my routers. I am not sure if there is a way to do it that is why I need help. 
I need a link to connect my Meraki Cisco router to Office365 Active directory. 
The field where you type in the IP address I need some type of a link or an unique login IP to microsoft office365 portal.

I have run out of solutions from google and my ideas so please can someone help me. Thank's in advance!

Comment: Network infrastructure Q's have their own SO site, try there.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to connect my Office 365 online Active directory to my routers.

What's your mean of "connect my Office 365 online Active directory to my routers"?

If you mean Azure AD, then all you need is internet connection. Azure AD is an internet-facing service. And if you want to sync your local AD accounts to the AAD, then you need the [AAD connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/).

If you mean the new feature called AAD Domain Service, then you need to create a site-to-site VPN between the Azure VNET Gateway and your router.